# List overwrite itselfs when i insert a new object into it

Tags: c#, list

First I initialise my `List<Set>` called myData where I store the data I got from an NMEA document. After that, I initialise my buffer which stores the data until a trigger takes place.

When I add a new Set to myData, all old existing data gets overwritten and only the newest data and X copies of it are left in myData.

```
    myData = new List<Set>();
    buffer = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "gps-koord.txt")))
        {
            string s;
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                {
                    if (s[0] == '$')
                    {
                        buffer.Add(s);
                        if (s.Contains("GPGGA"))
                        {
                            List<string> tmp = buffer.ToList();
                            myData.Add(new Set(tmp));
                            buffer = new List<string>();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + "gps-koord.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("Error, file not found");
    }
```

Comment: If the code you posted is the one you use to add a set to myData then on each call you're recreating myData so it will be empty, try with '`myData = myData ?? new List<Set>();`

Comment: its the init methode, it will only be called one time!

Comment: Then post the code which updates myData as there is where the error should be.

Comment: `myData.Add(new Set(tmp));` this line adds a new set of NMEA components to myData

Comment: Add the full code of the function, and you can remove the code you posted as it's not related to the problem and only causes confusion .

Comment: @Michael I cannot see anything wrong with the code you have posted maybe in simplifying the code to post you removed the error?

Comment: myData is a `List<T>` it's pre-implemented by the .NET framework, I think. Well, the main problems are caused by these lines: `List<string> tmp = buffer.ToList();
                            myData.Add(new Set(tmp));
                            buffer = new List<string>();` When the statement `if (s.Contains("GPGGA"))` is true a second time, all data stored in myData will become the same like the one i am going to add. It will look like this:

Data stored in myData: 1;
Then, i add the Number 2;
Data stoed in myData: 2, 2;
But it should be: 1, 2;

Comment: Are you sure you are not running this code as an async manner or from somewhere else in your code? Looks like myData list is actually placed at class scope

Comment: Yeah, i am only running these method, `List<Set> myData` is `public`